# form ModelMultipleChoiceField returns null [IntegrityError]

Tags: python, django

Using Django 4.0.5, Python 3.10.5.

I've created a form which should return a "match" model object. It properly displays "players" to choose from on a form, although after trying to save it I receive an `IntegrityError`, that I supposedly violate my not-null constraint. The failing row details are below:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "blackTeamPlayers_id" of relation "matches_match" violates not-null constraint
> DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2bc3f5f6-3249-4823-ae76-90fe44dc9c89, 2022-09-09, null, null).

The values that are passed are `UUID`, `date`, and two teams that are `ManyToManyFields` containing `Player` objects. I can't seem to understand why both team fields return null. Any help is appreciated, posting relevant code below. If anything besides that is required, I'll update it.

**forms.py [matches app]**

```py
class PlayerChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj: Player) -> str:
        return obj.nickname

class MatchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(), initial=datetime.date.today, label="Match Date")
    blackTeamPlayers = PlayerChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    whiteTeamPlayers = PlayerChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)    

class Meta:
    model = Match
    fields = ['date', 'blackTeamPlayers', 'whiteTeamPlayers']
```

**models.py [matches app]**

```py
class Match(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=False)
    blackTeamPlayers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player, related_name='%(class)s_black_team_players'
    )
    whiteTeamPlayers = models.ManyToManyField(
        Player, related_name='%(class)s_white_team_players'
    )
```

**views.py [matches app, relevant part]**

```py
class MatchCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name: str = 'add_match.html'
    form_class = MatchForm
    queryset = Match.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**models.py [players app]**

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("players:player_details", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was trivial, nothing wrong with the code. Please remember to `makemigrations` after playing around with your models...